# Real-time data push from server to iOS device WITHOUT APNS

Tags: ios, real-time, push

I'm building an iOS app which needs real-time updates from the server, and I'd like to accomplish this without polling.

Does anyone know of technologies, tools, products or libraries which would facilitate this functionality?

Comment: What speeds and messages per second are you looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) has an [Objective-C library](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher) and a REST API (along with a [number of libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries)) that would let you push realtime updates from your server into an iOS application.

I've also compiled a [list of realtime technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/) in which I'm sure you'll also find technologies that meet your requirements.