# IIS Streaming/Pushing JSON to iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, push

**Quick Version:**

I want to send timely data updates (in JSON) from an IIS WCF RESTfull webservice to an iOS custom-application. I don't want to poll due to bandwidth costs and the update-rate I need to achieve. My clients communicate to their server over the internet.

I'm confused by my options, and most of the information I read is out of date, targeted for web-browsers, or for media streaming.

Is there a current best-practice / standard-practice I should be using?

**Extra Details:**

- I have approx 25-100 iOS (v5.1) clients (iPads).
- I 'd like my clients to see an update within about 5 seconds of an event occurring.
- My clients are running 24x7, and communicate over a 3G network.
- The application only needs to receive the data while it is running (no requirement to show a notification when the app is minimized).
- Using a 3rd party service, or having to set-up a special server on my end is a no-go.
- Whatever I do needs to integrate nicely with my existing IIS WCF webservice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6837111/53313 (though the question is closed) provides some info.

Answer (score 0):

No additional research is required because you've asked a perfectly constrained question:

- There are only two choices:  push or pull, and pull is ruled out.
- There is only one way to push:  [APNS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).
- Without third party assistance, there's only one option:  build an APNs provider.

Comment: ..at a minimum there appears to be some options:SignalR, Websockets, socket.io, Comet of some type, using a JSONObjectWithStream approach.

...or are you saying none of these are viable?

Comment: You're right that a long-lived connection is an alternative to push or pull, but if bandwidth costs and update rate are ruling out polling, then wouldn't it also rule out sockets?

Comment: 100s is a tiny client audience.  Why do you rule out polling?

Comment: I'm not ruling out polling - if that's my only option then it will be the choice. I figure each poll will have a 2K http request, and a 1K empty response - that amounts to 53M/day/client in poll overhead. My events are relatively rare, almost all of the polls will return an empty response - thus push seems to make sense. I assume my push connection will be quiet (no data) for most of it's life.

Comment: Are you saying you need to post 2k every five seconds from client to server?  I think an empty response is in the tens of bytes, not 1k.